# Getting Facebook original image url

Tags: python, url, decode, decoding

I want to get the the original picture out of this Facebook link:

```
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCPdu0qFIMkMPGN&w=470&h=246&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-xfp1%2Fv%2Ft1.0-9%2F12705743_10153625263299678_1238692121976712825_n.jpg%3Foh%3D0f330b83cd6f52cba12b06ea141af571%26oe%3D5723078F&cfs=1&upscale=1&sx=1&sy=0&sw=558&sh=292&ext=png2jpg
```

What I usually do is get the value of `url` parameter and decode it to get the S3 link.
The result of applying this to this link is

```
https://scontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/12705743_10153625263299678_1238692121976712825_n.jpg
```

But it gives me 403 response. How should I obtain the link of the original photo?

Comment: That could be forbidden for reasons. Are you performing any sort of authentication through your code?

Comment: No, we get the first Url through the public image attached to the post. and we try to get the original url because we need bigger picture size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. I copied the url value of your first link and everything to the right into this online decoder:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

And obtained:

https://scontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/12705743_10153625263299678_1238692121976712825_n.jpg?oh=0f330b83cd6f52cba12b06ea141af571&oe=5723078F&cfs=1&upscale=1&sx=1&sy=0&sw=558&sh=292&ext=png2jpg

Which works fine.

Apparently the oh and oe parameter are essential. Here the minimal working link:

https://scontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/12705743_10153625263299678_1238692121976712825_n.jpg?oh=0f330b83cd6f52cba12b06ea141af571&oe=5723078F

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem. Thanks